# Differentiate home button click and incoming call in ios?

Tags: ios

Is there any solution to differentiate between Manually exiting app (via Home button clicking) and exiting app through incoming call?

Please help!!!

Comment: wt u want ???? and wt is ur problem ???

Comment: My problem is while running the App, if suppose i get a call and i had received it, then the App is entering into the background mode.  And if the call is been not Received its working fine. 

So my problem is i have to differentiate when the App is entering in Background mode in following two cases:
1.when manually exiting the app by Home button Click.
2.While receiving the Call.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sort of.

Clicking the home button or turning off the screen will result in your application being put into the background (`applicationDidEnterBackground`) while a phone call will not, and will just make your app resign its active status (`applicationWillResignActive`).

However, other actions such as raising the multitask bar will also cause your application to resign.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle home button click. But when user click home button or tap on app icon following *delegate* methods of *application* gets called. You can write code in that.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   /* Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
 Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
 */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
 If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
 */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
 */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
 */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Called when the application is about to terminate.
 Save data if appropriate.
 See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
 */
}
```

May it helps you to solve tour problem.