# Distinguish between Home Button Press and Incoming Call iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

Might be a dublicate question for the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744388/differentiate-home-button-click-and-incoming-call-in-ios). My problem is that, in my application the audio is being played as well as some animation is going on.
Now, the client wants to play the audio as well as the animation when the app goes to background which is not a problem. So, when a user clicks on HOME button the audio and the animation continues as it is. The problem is when the app is in foreground and the phone rings, the audio stops but the animation does not stop?

How can I distinguish the ways of app going to the background state so that when the phone call is coming I shall be able to pause the audio as well as the animation?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In home button press, application will go to Resign active AND background.

In Incoming call, Application will go to resign active.

I think this is what is answered in the link you provide.

Comment: When I press HOME button the APP goes to `(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` and then it goes to `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`.Same happens for a call .

Comment: Will resign active will be called every time when app goes to background also

Comment: So how can I distinguish the two ?

Comment: What exactly do u want to do? It is clear that if you want to press home button, you have to do something in `background`, and something that you want to do when call comes, you have to do that in `resign active`

Comment: Why you want to distinguish? The common things(applicable for phone call and background) put it in _applicationWillResignActive:_ other things leave to _applicationDidEnterBackground:_

Comment: Basically When I receive a phone call i want to pause the audio and the animation.Where should I write the code for the same?

Comment: in _applicationWillResignActive:_

Comment: So if I perss the home button won't this method be called?

Comment: obviously it will call.. What do you want? do you want not to stop animation when entering in background? Actually why you are performing animation when app is in background.. who is going to see that????

Comment: What I want is if the home button is pressed then the audio as well as the animation should not stop and when the call is coming both the audio and the animation should stop.

Comment: Secondly the animation and audio is in sync So I cant stop any one.Either I have to stop both or none.

Comment: when user receive call both methods are called

Answer (score -1):

// Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
That time this delegate will be called.

```
 - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

/ Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits. or when the user press the home button.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

And note that when you press home button that time applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground both will be called.